# Where does the Azure DevOps/TFS cache extensions data

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-server-2019

I have developed Azure DevOps extension and published it to marketplace. Recently I have came across mandatory UI changes. While performing dev testing, I have noticed that once I install new extension (with UI changes) it still showing old UI components. 
For example, let’s say I have string input named “Name” and I have replaced it with “Full Name”. I still see my old input which is “Name”.

Old :

```
{
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Name",
            "required": true            
}
```

New:

```
{
            "name": "fullName",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Full Name",
            "required": true            
}
```

I removed temp files under below locations, but issue persists.

- C:\Users\<< User Name >>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\
- << Agent Folder >> \ _Work\
- Windows Temp folder

I have changed the task id (GUID) and it seems resolving this issue. But this is not viable solution as I cannot issue new task id for already published extension.

Due to this reason I believe best option to resolve this issue is deleting cached data. Please let me know, Where does the Azure DevOps / TFS cache it’s extension data?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is cleaning browser cache and increasing the version number in the task.json helpful?

Comment: I usually close all browsers or do a Ctrl-F5 before triggering a new build after a component change but it is still sometime on the old version for one or two build/release.  After it downloads the new one.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT , Thank you for your response. Sometimes it fixes the issue but some times not. Better if we have concrete solution for this.

Comment: @Lalindu Do you try Delete task -- Save definition -- add task again? Is it helpful?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT , Yes, Seems this works fine for most of scenarios. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean the browser cache, and check whether you have increase the version number in the task.json.

Also, try to Delete task -- Save definition -- add task again, which should help.

Answer (score 1):

For me solution with updating task version and removing browser cache didn't work. I found the `DistributedTask` folder in one of subfolders in [the root cache folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/change-caching-app-tier?view=azure-devops#specify-diff-cache-root). In my case it was `cache_root_folder/<some_uuid>/Proxy/<another_uuid>/DistrebutedTask/`. I dont know what these UUIDs mean and found this path just accidentally. Removing all from this folder helped.

Comment: Thank you @Nikita I will try this as well